# python + Spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-sheets

Can anybody please tell me is there any possible way to connect to spreadsheet from python? I want to store some data from a form and submit it to google spreadsheet. Please help on this issue. What steps do I have to follow?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to connect to Google Spreadsheet is by using this [spreadsheet library](http://burnash.github.com/gspread). These are the steps you need to follow:

```
import gspread

# Login with your Google account
gc = gspread.login('account@gmail.com','password')

# Spreadsheets can be opened by their title in Google Docs
spreadsheet = gc.open("_YOUR_TARGET_SPREADSHEET_")

# Select worksheet by index
worksheet = spreadsheet.get_worksheet(0)

# Update cell with your form value
worksheet.update_cell(1, 2, form_value_1)
```

Comment: I have installed the lib gspread but getting following error   ImportError: No module named gspread

Comment: @AnilUgale that error means you haven't installed gspread or you have installed it incorrectly. Try to install it with pip or easy_install.

Comment: Thanks for response but sir I have installed Gspread with pip and it has given message gpread is installed successfully. But still facing same error."No module named gspread  "

Answer (score 1):

There is a python api for google docs http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/gdata/articles/python_client_lib.html. I am not sure if it works with app engine

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can validate with OAuth then use the gdata Python API -- see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/gdata-python-client-library-contributors/browse_thread/thread/19d93048d9914cd6) for more details and caveats, [this code](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/oauth/oauth_on_appengine) for a good simple example of OAuth use in Python on App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple wrapper for the Google Spreasheets API i've recently written:

http://github.com/yoavaviram/python-google-spreadsheet

Its compatible with App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently written a module to do this.  check it out https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyworkbooks/